# Google Calendar Search

Tags: search, calendar

Is the New Google Calendar API provide any method so that I can search any user public calendar using his/her email Address.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available in one of google calendar's docs here- http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_js.html

```
var myService;
var feedUrl = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/liz@gmail.com/public/full";

function setupMyService() {
  myService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1');
}

function getMyFeed() {
  setupMyService();

  myService.getEventsFeed(feedUrl, handleMyFeed, handleError);
}
```

Also, there are some threads which discuss the same issue of fetching feeds from public calendars.

1) http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=5f8c3bf4b9836bd1&hl=en

2) http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=2e8b8003b1aa5fd9&hl=en